# a good cross browser javascript library for building desktop/os styled web applications?

Tags: javascript, gwt, web-applications, desktop-application, vaadin

basically I want to create a browser form (it will load an external page by iframe. but around the iframe is something that resembles a desktop operating system actual browser. Complete with icons, addressbar, file menus. ex. IE6 themed browser component inside the browser. Also should be very responsive, almost as if they were using a flash application.

Something like GWT, Vaadin.

It also would be great to have some windows GUI kit to build the ui's by dragging and dropping, double clicking on it to add events and stuff like that.

Trying to build something like http://www.lfsworld.net/. Click on login as Guest and see the desktop in your browser.

Comment: Check out examples of ExtJS framework... What is the Question BTW ?

Comment: [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/desktop/desktop.html) in particular

Comment: is there a drag and drop gui builder?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement drag and drop why don't you check [gwt-dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/)?
You can add doubleClick,drag and drop handlers. This library is well documented and there are plenty of demos to play with.